# Showing a polynomial is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a question that asks me to show that the set $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x + 2y + 3z = 1\} $ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ under the regular addition and scalar multiplication. I understand that to prove a subspace I have to show that it is closed under addition and under scalar multiplication. Or I show that there exists a **0** such that **0** + **u** = **u** and there exists a negative of **u** such that **u** + (-**u**) = **0**.

I can't figure out a way to show that one of them doesn't work. Could someone help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Can you see $(0,0,0)\not\in S$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not sure if it's my laptop or if I'm doing it wrong. It's not working for me. Thank you though. I'll work on it.

Comment: $(1,0,0)\in S$. However, $2\cdot (1, 0, 0)$ is not in $S$. Since the question asks you to show that both addition and scalar multiplication are not working, you need to do more work: Just choose another vector in $S$,say $(0, 1/2, 0)$ and verify directly.

Comment: The first thing we check when we want to show that something is not a subspace is often if the zero vector is included, which it is not in this case. Thus $S$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $W$ is a subspace of $V \implies$ $\forall w_1,w_2 \in W$ the vector $w_1+w_2 \in W$.

Let $W=S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1+2x_2+3x_3=1\}$ and $V=\mathbb R^3$.
If we now take $w_1=(2,1,-1)$ and $w_2=(0,-1,1)$, they belong to $S$ but $w_1+w_2=(2,0,0)\notin S$.
This shows that $S$ can't be a subspace of $\mathbb R^3.$